# How can you write information from multiple textboxes with multiple lines per textbox to a CSV file?

Tags: c#, winforms

So I'm writing a program where I input 3 values into a textbox which then gets displayed in another textbox (the input textbox then gets cleared), the moment you click the "confirm" button you get a prompt of where you want to save this file and with which name.

I've got this code at the moment:

```
        private void btnBevestig_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Plek kiezen van opslag, keuze verifieren
        {
            if(MessageBox.Show("Bent u zeker?", "Confirmatie", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                txtUID.Text = string.Empty;
                txtDescriptionButton.Text = string.Empty;
                txtArduinoContact.Text = string.Empty;
                txtArtikelNaam.Text = string.Empty;
            } 
        }

        private void btnInvoeren_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            try
            {
                if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(txtInvUID.Text, "[^0-9]"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Je mag alleen nummers invoeren.");
                    txtInvUID.Text = txtInvUID.Text.Remove(txtInvUID.Text.Length - 1);
                }
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtInvUID.Text)) {
                    MessageBox.Show("Het vakje UID is leeg", "Informatie", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                }
                else if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtInvDescriptionButton.Text)) {
                    MessageBox.Show("Het vakje Description button is leeg", "Informatie", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                }
                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtInvArduinoContact.Text))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Het vakje Arduino contact is leeg", "Informatie", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                }
                else
                {
                    txtUID.Text = txtInvUID.Text + "\r\n" + txtUID.Text;
                    txtDescriptionButton.Text = txtInvDescriptionButton.Text + "\r\n" + txtDescriptionButton.Text;
                    txtArduinoContact.Text = txtInvArduinoContact.Text + "\r\n" + txtArduinoContact.Text;

                    txtInvUID.Text = string.Empty;
                    txtInvDescriptionButton.Text = string.Empty;
                    txtInvArduinoContact.Text = string.Empty;

                }
            }   
            catch(Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message, "Fout", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
        }
```

In short: txtUID, txtDescriptionButton and txtArduinoContact are the textboxes where the information gets saved, I need this information to be written away into a CSV file, and the first line needs to be UID, DSCRBUTTON and ARDUICONTACT.

Comment: What have you tried so far? what research have you done? There are plenty of examples on how to write a csv file. This case seem to be quite straightforward unless I have missed anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this method.

```
public void WriteToCSV()
{
   var csv = new StringBuilder();
   for (int i = 0; i < txtInvUID.Lines.Length; i++)
   {
       var newLine = string.Format("{0}", txtInvUID.Lines[i] + Environment.NewLine);
       csv.AppendLine(newLine);
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < txtUID.Lines.Length; i++)
   {
       var newLine = string.Format("{0}", txtUID.Lines[i] + Environment.NewLine);
       csv.AppendLine(newLine);
   }

        

   for (int i = 0; i < txtInvDescriptionButton.Lines.Length; i++)
   {
       var newLine = string.Format("{0}", txtInvDescriptionButton.Lines[i] + Environment.NewLine);
       csv.AppendLine(newLine);
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < txtDescriptionButton.Lines.Length; i++)
   {
       var newLine = string.Format("{0}", txtDescriptionButton.Lines[i] + Environment.NewLine);
       csv.AppendLine(newLine);
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < txtInvArduinoContact.Lines.Length; i++)
   {
       var newLine = string.Format("{0}", txtInvArduinoContact.Lines[i] + Environment.NewLine);
       csv.AppendLine(newLine);
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < txtArduinoContact.Lines.Length; i++)
   {
       var newLine = string.Format("{0}", txtArduinoContact.Lines[i] + Environment.NewLine);
       csv.AppendLine(newLine);
   }


   string fileName = @"D:\WriteText.csv";
   if (File.Exists(fileName))
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(fileName, csv.ToString());
    else
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, csv.ToString());
}
```